# What is difference between CascadeType.ALL, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE and orphanRemoval

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persist

I searched the answer but I could not get it properly. What is difference between `CascadeType.ALL`, cascade = `CascadeType.REMOVE`, `orphanRemoval` when we set `FetchType.EAGER` on `@OneToMany` relationship?
Once I had a problem while deleteing records. I have used following

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "companyEntity", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
Set<EmployeeEntity> employeeEntities;
```

When I tried to delete Employee record, it was not showing me any exception and it was not deleteing record. But when I changed `CascadeType.ALL` to `CascadeType.REMOVE` then it was working.
Why it was not working with `CascadeType.ALL` rather with `CascadeType.REMOVE`?

Thank you for simple explanation in advance ;)

Answer (score 4):

[This](http://nsinfra.blogspot.in/2013/03/jpa-20-hibernate-orphanremoval-true.html) explains part of your question.

> 'OrphanRemoval=true' Vs 'CascadeType.REMOVE'
>
> The difference between the two settings is in the response to removing
>   child objects from the collection pointed by parent entity.
>
> If orphanRemoval=true is specified the removed address instance is
>   automatically removed. If only cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE is specified
>   no automatic action is taken since removing a relationship is not a
>   remove operation.