# JDBC Error Column cannot be null on child join table when deleting a parent record

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have the following parent model:

```
public class RdResponses extends Model implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    // child records
    @JoinColumn(name = "response_id", nullable = false)
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<GenProtectionNeed> genProtectionNeedList;

    /* setters and getters omitted for brevity */
}
```

The child class:

```
public class GenProtectionNeed extends Model implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
    
    // reference back to parent
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "genProtectionNeedId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<GenMeasures> genMeasuresList;
    
    @JoinColumn(name = "network_access_value_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private CmsNetworkAccessValues networkAccessValueId;

    /* setters and getters omitted */

}
```

So, in my controller, I call the following:

```
    responseService.responses().delete(response);
```

This results in the following SQL error:

```
2021-04-14 23:20:44.379 ERROR 212817 --- [21-7000-exec-11] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'network_access_value_id' cannot be null
```

I am not entirely sure why JPA/Hibernate are trying to set the value of this field to `NULL`, but in doing so - it is throwing this JDBC error. I am fairly confident the error lies in my code somewhere - since when I do a manual delete on the record in MySQL, it deletes and cascades correctly.

What do I have set incorrectly? I have tried a mixture of different CascadeType's, along with setting mappedBy on the OneToMany side of the relationship, to no avail.

Comment: Are you using the lastest Hibernate version 5.4.30? If so, and you still have the problem, please create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0):

using `CascadeType.REMOVE` in your RdResponses class may solve your problem.

Comment: Wouldn't that be included under CascadeTypes.ALL?

Comment: yes but there is a difference between these two see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27855362/what-is-difference-between-cascadetype-all-cascade-cascadetype-remove-and-orp

Comment: Adding CascadeType.REMOVE did not change the error

Comment: have you removed orphanRemoval = true?

Comment: Yes, I did. It still reports the same error on that field